# Nested python list assignment

Tags: python

What I want to do is assign a nested list to another list. For example, from alist to blist.

```
alist = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
blist = alist[:]
blist[0].append(1)
```

In this way, `id(alist[0])` equals `id(alist[1])`, so alist also changes to `[[0,1], [1], [2], [3]]`, that's not what I want.

The workaround I have is:

```
alist = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
blist = []
for item in alist:
    blist.append(item[:])
blist[0].append(1)
```

In this workaround, alist won't be influenced by changing blist's items.
However, it seems not so pythonic, is there any better resolution? That could resolve the deep copy of more the 2 level nested list. eg: `alist = [[[1], 10], [[2], 20], [[3], 30]]`

Comment: Your workaround can be written more simply as: `blist = [item[:] for item in alist]` or what I prefer `[list(item) for item in alist]`. However the solution by @cha0site is the proper way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to use `copy.deepcopy()`, this also resolves deeper copies:

```
>>> import copy
>>> alist = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> blist = copy.deepcopy(alist)
>>> blist[0].append(1)
>>> alist
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> blist
[[0, 1], [1], [2], [3]]
```